# Dual monitor setup issue, 2nd monitor detected but goes black screen every once in a while for 1-2 seconds when playing video games

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I bought a ViewSonic VA2432 monitor yesterday which is 75hz, 24 inches, and IPS panel. Ever so often, my monitor gives a black screen whenever I play video games or just simply voice chatting with my friends on discord. I use the HDMI cable that came along the monitor. I use this ViewSonic Monitor as my main screen and my laptop monitor as my secondary screen simply because this viewsonic monitor has a wider screen. My laptop is an Asus TUF FX504 series with 12GB RAM and Nvidia 1050ti graphics card. I tried every possible solution on the internet with updating my monitor drivers, graphics drivers, and even turning off the settings on my PCI Express while on High Performance battery mode. I also tried a different HDMI cable instead of the free cable that came with the monitor.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

update: the monitor would only go black whenever I'm using an application that uses my microphone (Discord)

Comment: Can you try changing your screen settings to 'Second Screen Only'? Might help :)

Comment: Yes but then that would defeat the purpose of having a double monitor setup since it would be very useful to me for multitasking.

Comment: Are you connecting the cable directly to the laptop? I've had a similar issue with a docking station in the past.

Comment: Yes it's connected to my laptop using the HDMI to HDMI cable that came with the monitor. What's weird is after using it for 1 week, I noticed that the constant black screen would only happen whenever I'm using an application that uses my microphone (like discord)

Comment: how were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and the same problem as you.
What fixes the problem for me is using a wireless connected microphone instead of a wired one.
For example I use both wired and bluetooth earphones at the same time. I use the wired ones for the output and the bluetooth ones for the input and I make sure the bluetooth ones are set as input in all voice applications.